# Applescript combining repeat commands

Tags: automation, applescript

Pretty simple question:
Is there a possible way to do 
`repeat 10 times or until "Terminal" window exists`
?

Comment: No, the `repeat` command allows you to either test for a condition, or count, but not both at once.  So you have to pick one, then implement the other yourself inside the loop, as demonstrated nicely by @wch1zpink.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
repeat 10 times
    if application "Terminal" is running then
        tell application "Terminal" to if window 1 exists then exit repeat
    end if
    delay 0.1
end repeat
```

**OR This**

```
repeat 10 times
    if application "Terminal" is running then
        tell application "Terminal"
            if windows exists then
                tell me to beep 1 -- some optional command
                exit repeat
            end if
        end tell
    end if
    delay 0.1
end repeat
```